# How to keep complete Solr index in memory?

Tags: java, caching, solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am running a Solr cluster with 6 nodes. Currently I evaluate the performance of the cluster. Articles about Solr tuning (like [Solr Cache Tuning](https://teaspoon-consulting.com/articles/solr-cache-tuning.html) or [High Performance Solr](http://de.slideshare.net/shalinmangar/high-performance-solr) or [Solr Caching](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching)) speak about caches and JVM tuning. But what I am interested in is how I can configure Solr to hold the complete index in memory (like an in-memory database). As I am not using the HDFSDirectory which has a parameter for block caches, I wonder if there is something similar for the "normal" Directory implementation?

Comment: In addition to the RAMDirectory (which will give you an memory only-index), remember that modern OS-es disk caches most io requests as long as the memory is available.

Comment: That's right. As long as you sufficiently warm-up the index with a few queries, the OS will take care of caching the index in memory provided there's enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RAMDirectory which will store and query everything from the memory.

Comment: The comment in `solrconfig.xml`states that `solr.RAMDirectoryFactory is memory based, not persistent, and doesn't work with replication.` So it is not the solution I am looking for.

Comment: yes that's right. didn't understood that your have persistence requirements. sorry